# Microsoft Teams HttpPost Action fails with BadRequest

Tags: http-post, microsoft-teams, card, office365connectors

We use the [Incoming Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) feature to send notifications from our application backend to our **internal Teams channel** in some situations that require employee intervention (This is *not* a question about some kind of public Teams integration).
I'm trying to add actionable notifications to our Teams workflow by adding an `HttpPost` action to our messages:

```json
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "Manual Verification Required",
    "themeColor": "#2196F3",
    "text": "<message content here>",
    "title": "Manual Verification Required",
    "potentialAction": [
        {
            "@type": "HttpPOST",
            "name": "Approve",
            "target": "https://our.application.host/.teams/webhook",
            "body": "verification.approve"
        }
    ]
}
```

The message arrives in teams properly:

[image: message in Teams]

Upon clicking the button though, immediately the following error message appears:

> ⚠️ **Failed to send:**
> There was a problem submitting your changes. Try again in a minute.

After scratching my head, I opened the Teams webapp and checked the console:

```
POST https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/19:0d89db468868447a8e526a258788b854@thread.tacv2;messageid=1615721159117/1615721159117/executeAction 400

2021-03-14T11:30:20.322Z [O365ActionPaneController.makeHttpPOSTRequestForConnector()] Http invoke failed: {
  "data": {
    "errorCode": "BadRequest"
  },
  "status": 400,
  "config": {
    "method": "POST",
    "transformRequest": [
      null
    ],
    "transformResponse": [
      null
    ],
    "url": "https://teams.microsoft.com/api/mt/emea/beta/users/connectors/19:0d89db468868447a8e526a258788b854@thread.tacv2;messageid=1615721159117/1615721159117/executeAction",
    "data": {
      "inputParameters": [],
      "actionId": "3c5b2184-bffb-4797-9bbd-03fe41e11a83",
      "potentialAction": "{\"@type\":\"HttpPOST\",\"@id\":\"3c5b2184-bffb-4797-9bbd-03fe41e11a83\",\"name\":\"Approve\",\"target\":\"https://our.appplication.host/.teams/webhook\",\"headers\":[],\"body\":\"verification.approve\",\"bodyContentType\":\"\"}",
      "name": "action/connector",
      "integrationId": "8urpi87b0u",
      "meta": "\"{\\\"connectorSenderGuid\\\":\\\"203a1e2c-26cc-47ca-83ae-be98f960b6b2\\\",\\\"providerAccountUniqueId\\\":null,\\\"connectorConfigurationAlternateId\\\":\\\"8a43fac7aa1748688609de3602c9a4c5\\\"}\"",
      "clientInfo": {
        "locale": "en-us",
        "country": "us",
        "platform": "Web",
        "clientVersion": "1415/1.0.0.2021030227"
      }
    },
    "headers": {
      "X-Skypetoken": "pii",
      "Authorization": "pii",
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "X-RingOverride": "general",
      "x-ms-scenario-id": "620",
      "x-ms-user-type": null,
      "x-ms-client-type": "web",
      "x-ms-client-env": "pckgsvc-prod-c1-euno-02",
      "x-ms-client-version": "1415/1.0.0.2021030227",
      "x-ms-session-id": "694afe93-2218-14ab-fd16-d46edaf9fcc5"
    },
    "counter": "ext_actionable_card_http_post",
    "geoRoutingLookupDuration": 0.014999997802078724,
    "decrementNetworkRequests": null,
    "hostName": "teams.microsoft.com",
    "requestCreationDuration": 0.09000004455447197,
    "requestStartTime": 3355762.155000033,
    "responseStartTime": 3356549.715000001,
    "requestDuration": 787.5649999482557
  },
  "statusText": ""
}
```

So the only valuable information returned from the server seems to be the response `{"errorCode":"BadRequest"}`. That's a little thin.

I tried different variations of the `body` property - with quotes, without, with a content type, empty - no change.

**What do I have to do to get message actions working?**

Comment: Hi @Moritz Friedrich, I am unable to repro the issue. I have followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#example-connector-message). Can you please provide valid target url in HttpPost action.

Comment: Hi @Sridevi-MSFT, I replaced our working, publicly available, HTTPS target URL with an example value in the output above, as I don't think its relevant to the question. I tested calling the target URL with curl, which successfully returns a Status 200 in ~30ms.

Comment: Hey again @Sridevi-MSFT is there anything I can do to learn more about this error? Surely the Teams infrastructure logs the cause of `BadRequest` exceptions somewhere? The result of this cannot simply be that a reproduction is impossible. We have a subscription and I'm sending messages exactly as per the documentation, so this seems to be a bug in the product. I'm grateful for any help, just a little lost here. What is the suggested procedure?

Comment: I have reproduced the same code that you have provided and tested with my working target URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxkm6.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/awyRh.png, its working completely fine. I think the issue is with your target URL could you please check your target URL in postman.

Comment: As of today, the message action works. Nothing about the code changed; the target URL works flawlessly from curl or Postman; until now, the access log didn't even show any request made by Microsoft servers, so I'm absolutely sure there was some kind of bug in the Teams infrastructure.
You can consider this issue solved, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the same code that you have provided and tested with my working target URL, its working completely fine. I think the issue is with your target URL could you please check your target URL in postman.
[image][image]

Comment: According to git, we made the last change to the target URL endpoint on March, 14: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOKd6.png. As of today, the HTTPPost suddenly works. This was not an issue with the target URL, but with Teams. It doesn't really matter now, but the answer is _not_ that there was something wrong on our side. Maybe the most important takeaway here is that the Teams error messages aren't helpful enough :)